# Exception SQL Oracle - Update and Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, procedure, cursor

Tenho uma duvida referente a uma procedure que estou fazendo banco oracle.
Uma pequena explicação para o que estou fazendo: Estou lendo dados de uma tabela, e jogando eles em um cursor, depois de jogar no cursor, jogo ele pra um recorde, no procedimento eu tenho 2 update e 10 inserts, em tabelas diferentes.

A minha duvida é a seguinte, caso algum desses procedimentos der algo errado, eu dar um rollback, em tudo o que já foi feito. Existe alguma exception do oracle que eu consiga tratar isso, para os update e inserts e rollblack?

Comment: VIDE https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm

Answer (score 4):

Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Se você está querendo tratar um erro, precisa saber que tipo de erro ele é.

Por exemplo:

```
begin
  insert into TABELA(id, coluna1) values (1, 'Valor1);
exception
  when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then 
    -- Aqui faço o tratamento se o registro já existia.
  when OTHERS then
    -- Qualquer outro erro vai cair aqui
end;
```

Procure estudar um pouco sobre tratamento de exceptions que vale a pena.

Abs